# Bootstrap 4 toggle content inside responsive hidden col?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 to design the website that has 3 columns, with the left most column hidden on mobile and tablet. The code are like this

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 d-none d-sm-none d-md-block" id="left-sidebar">
            <div id="left-block">
              <ul>
                <li>One</li>
                <li>Two</li>
                <li>Three</li>
                <li>Four</li>
                <li>Five</li>
                <li>Six</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6" id="main-content">
            <button id="toggle-button" class="btn btn-primary d-block d-sm-block d-md-none" role="button">show left sidebar</button>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3" id="right-sidebar">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#left-sidebar{background-color:#ffcccc;}
@media (max-width: 768px) { 
  #left-sidebar{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;overflow-y:scroll;z-index:10000;}
}
```

JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#toggle-button" ).click(function() {
       $("#left-sidebar").show();
    });
});
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/TrafalgarLaw119/pen/yRQWoY

What I'm trying to do is to add button that when clicked, will show the sidebar over page content. My problem is I couldn't get the sidebar to show. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the html of your first column to:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-3 collapse d-md-block" id="left-sidebar">
  <div id="left-block">
    <ul>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
      <li>Four</li>
      <li>Five</li>
      <li>Six</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

d-none meanse display: block !important, so the jquery won't overwrite it, bootstrap class collapse just means display: block;

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `d-none d-sm-none d-md-block` in `left-sidebar` put the `display` property in your style:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) { 
 #left-sidebar{
  position:fixed;top:0;left:0;overflow-y:scroll;z-index:10000; 
  display: none; /* add this property */
 }
}
```